How can I calculate the cumulative sum of values in a changing time window using Pandas?
I need to know the amount of rainfall between two consecutive measurements of soil moisture (SM) and the difference in soil moisture (deltaSM).
df= pd.read_excel('Dataset.xlsx')

df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df=df.set_index('Datetime')

My data look like this:
Date         SM   Rain
01/01/2016   0.23   0
02/01/2016     -    0
03/01/2016     -    10
04/01/2016   0.15   0
05/01/2016   0.30   0.1
06/01/2016     -    0
07/01/2016     -    5.2
08/01/2016     -    12.3
05/01/2016   0.40   0.5
06/01/2016     -    0
07/01/2016   0.25   0
08/01/2016     -    0
.
.
.

I would like to get:
Date         SM   Rain  deltaSM  Rsum
01/01/2016   0.23   0      -      0
02/01/2016     -    0      -      -
03/01/2016     -    10     -      -
04/01/2016   0.15   0    -0.08    10.0
05/01/2016   0.30   0.1   0.15    0.1
06/01/2016     -    0      -      -
07/01/2016     -    5.2    -      -
08/01/2016     -    12.3   -      -
05/01/2016   0.40   0.5   0.10    18.0
06/01/2016     -    0      -      -
07/01/2016   0.25   0    -0.15    0
08/01/2016     -    0      -      -

I'm a beginner, I tried different approaches but failed to work. Thanks for any help you can give me!

what did you try? Show it in question, not in comments.

because you have to cumulate values in different number of rows so maybe you would have to use normal for-loop to run complex code which remember previous data and run calculations only when there is value in SM

What's up with the dates? They're out of order and duplicated. I wrote some code that gets the desired output, but it ignores the dates entirely, so IDK if my code is wrong or the example data / description is wrong.

You can identify the numeric rows in SM, then use this to compute a mask for diff and a grouper for groupby.sum/groupby.transform:
s = pd.to_numeric(df['SM'], errors='coerce')
m = s.notna()

df['deltaSM'] = s[m].diff()

df.loc[m, 'Rsum'] = df['Rain'].groupby(m[::-1].cumsum()).transform('sum')

# or
# df.loc[m, 'Rsum'] = (df['Rain']
#                      .groupby(m[::-1].cumsum(), sort=False)
#                      .sum().values[:-1]
#                      )

Output:
          Date    SM  Rain  deltaSM  Rsum
0   01/01/2016  0.23   0.0      NaN   0.0
1   02/01/2016     -   0.0      NaN   NaN
2   03/01/2016     -  10.0      NaN   NaN
3   04/01/2016  0.15   0.0    -0.08  10.0
4   05/01/2016  0.30   0.1     0.15   0.1
5   06/01/2016     -   0.0      NaN   NaN
6   07/01/2016     -   5.2      NaN   NaN
7   08/01/2016     -  12.3      NaN   NaN
8   05/01/2016  0.40   0.5     0.10  18.0
9   06/01/2016     -   0.0      NaN   NaN
10  07/01/2016  0.25   0.0    -0.15   0.0
11  08/01/2016     -   0.0      NaN   NaN


The solution of @mozway great. Here I made longer way solution, I just wanted to share from long way:))
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'Date': ['01/01/2016', '02/01/2016', '03/01/2016', '04/01/2016', '05/01/2016', 
             '06/01/2016', '07/01/2016', '08/01/2016', '05/01/2016', '06/01/2016', 
             '07/01/2016', '08/01/2016'],
    'SM': [0.23, None, None, 0.15, 0.30, None, None, None, 0.40, None, 0.25, None],
    'Rain': [0, 0, 10, 0, 0.1, 0, 5.2, 12.3, 0.5, 0, 0, 0]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize columns for deltaSM and Rsum
df['deltaSM'] = '-'
df['Rsum'] = '-'

# Variables to track the previous SM value and cumulative Rain sum
prev_sm = None
cum_rain = 0

# Iterate through the DataFrame to calculate deltaSM and Rsum
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    cum_rain += row['Rain']
    print('index: ', idx, '-', row['SM'], row['Rain'])
    if pd.notna(row['SM']):
        if prev_sm is not None:
            df.at[idx, 'deltaSM'] = row['SM'] - prev_sm
            df.at[idx, 'Rsum'] = cum_rain
            cum_rain = 0  # Reset cumulative Rain sum after calculation
        prev_sm = row['SM']
    

# Convert 'deltaSM' and 'Rsum' columns to proper types
df['deltaSM'] = pd.to_numeric(df['deltaSM'], errors='coerce')
df['Rsum'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rsum'], errors='coerce')

# Convert 'Date' to datetime and set as index
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.set_index('Date')

print(df)

